# Copying a lot of files failed by using smb:\\serverip in nautils

Tags: windows, samba

Copying a lot of files failed by using smb:\serverip in nautils

I was copying a lot of photos from windows server to my ubuntu desktop. At beginning, it looked ok. But nautils progress bar stop updating after a while and the copying suspend.

Seems like it's not reliable to use nautils samba.

I was using ubuntu desktop 13.10 desktop 64 bit. Copying folder from windows server 2008 R2. In the folder, there are over 11,000 photos. The progress stuck around 3000 photos, and the photo size is around 5-6kb. Any workaround should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the progress bar dissapears but the background process is still there, seems at the start the it is sticked at dome kb's but if you refresh the folder you can see the files growing. Definitively a bug.